# Multiple Elements with same Ids get generated using bootstrap-responsive-tabs

Tags: jquery, html, responsive, bootstrap-tabs

I am using [bootstrap-responsive-tabs.js](https://github.com/openam/bootstrap-responsive-tabs) for showing tabs in mobile view.
Problem is the tabs and the list of tabs coming in dropdown is having same ids.
The dropdown elements are generated by the plugin.

My custom jquery functions which tries to find the element by id fails in this case. 
How can I fix this issue?
This is the html generated by the plugin

```
    <div class="responsive-tabs-container clearfix">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs detailPageTab js-example responsive-tabs" role="tablist" style="">
  <li id="detailsTab" class="hide-tab js-tab cnt-tselected hidden" tab-id="1" tab-index="0" tabitem-id="detailsTab" style="width: 100%;"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class=""></i>Details</a></li>
  <li id="logsTab" class="hide-tab js-tab hidden" style="display: list-item; width: 100%;" tab-id="2" tab-index="1" tabitem-id="detailsTab"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Logs</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right dropdown tabs-dropdown js-tabs-dropdown">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="count">Tabs</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <div class="dropdown-header visible-xs">
    <p class="count">
     Tabs
    </p>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="dropdown"><span>×</span></button>
    <div class="divider visible-xs">
    </div>
   </div>
   <li id="detailsTab" class="hide-tab js-tab" tab-id="1" tab-index="0"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class=""></i>Details</a></li>
   <li id="logsTab" class="hide-tab js-tab" style="display: none" tab-id="2" tab-index="1"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Logs</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show your jquery as if it is done by bootstrap plugin we can suggest on your jquery.

Comment: For example I will be having a display none on some of the tabs and based on some conditions I will be showing them like $("#"+id).show() . But it doesn't work since there are two elements. $(element[id="id"]).show() will work but I have so many cases like this and I am doing mobile responsive view for an already implemented project.